# Which system variables are exposed from browser JavaScript context?

Tags: web-browser, fingerprinting, environment-variables

I know that the `TZ` variable aka TimeZone can be read by servers, especially with fingerprinting.

What are the exposed variables to browser's ?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Doesn't TZ stand for Time Zulu? It should be cross-platform, how to console.log is a programming question I'm afraid

Comment: Forget about `console.log()` then

Comment: What do you mean by “system variable”?

Comment: Like `$TZ` on Linux. Or how fingerprinting knows your timezone?